# O que é Reactive Programming (Programação Reativa)?

Tags: programação-funcional, reactive-programming

Alguém pode me explicar de forma clara e objetiva?

Eu li alguns artigos mais ainda não ficou muito claro.

Comment: http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming

Comment: Esse é o melhor material que já lí sobre o assunto: https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Programação reativa é programar com fluxos(streams) de dados assíncronos.
Assíncrono significa que não se realiza ao mesmo tempo ou no mesmo ritmo de desenvolvimento (em relação a outra coisa).

Isso é importante devido o crescimento da Internet e a demanda por tempo real, a programação precisa ser dinâmica, ou seja; diferente da forma tradicional de desenvolvimento.

A forma tradicional de programar/desenvolver, por exemplo, cria várias tarefas e elas se comunicam em tempos determinados, com respostas determinadas sem escalabilidade caso ocorra alguma falha, alguma demanda maior, são "rígidas", seguem regras diretas. Isto funcionava e continua sendo utilizada até hoje, entretanto esta "lógica" não é mais compatível com a necessidade atual.

No método tradicional é como preparar a mistura do cimento, depois que este enviou os dados dizendo que está preparado, é chamada a função de construir a parede, depois o reboco, esperar um tempo determinado, passado o período é chamada a função de pintar e se faltar o pintor? Ferrou tudo, deu erro no sistema! Ou se a comunicação falhar? Erro também, sistema trava, geralmente é preciso refazer tudo!

Na programação reativa isso tudo ocorre, mas de forma inteligente, interligada em paralelo, sem seguir aquela ordem cronológica e linear, como por exemplo: a parede esta construída, falta o reboco, tempo pra secar, depois pintar. Não tem pintor, falha nesta tarefa, o sistema não irá travar, reconhece que é possível continuar outras partes da construção em paralelo como o chão, botar o piso, enquanto fica em espera a tarefa de pintar, sem ter que recomeçar tudo outra vez, concluir depois a pintura, sem ter sido interrompido o sistema pelo "erro".

É por aí a lógica, parece meio óbvio se for pensar, mas os sistemas ainda são pouco inteligentes, precisam ser devidamente programados para estarem aptos a gerenciar falhas, rotinas diferentes, seguir caminhos alternativos, muitos acessos, funcionar em tempo real e sempre estar online/ativo!

**Seguem os pilares da programação reativa:**

- **Elástico**: Reage à demanda/carga: aplicações podem fazer uso de
  múltiplos núcleos e múltiplos servidores;
- **Resiliente**: Reage às falhas; aplicações reagem e se recuperam de
  falhas de software, hardware e de conectividade;
- **Message Driven:** Reage aos eventos (*event driven*): em vez de compor
  aplicações por múltiplas *threads* síncronas, sistemas são compostos de 
  gerenciadores de eventos assíncronos e não bloqueantes;
- **Responsivo**: Reage aos usuários: aplicações que oferecem interações
  ricas e “tempo real” com usuários.

Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados [nesse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4zRhjSto8U&t=27) e [nesse artigo](http://blog.andrefaria.com/programacao-reativa-reactive-programming).