# O que são e quais são as principais diferenças entre Programação Funcional e Programação Reativa?

Tags: programação-funcional, paradigma-de-programação, programação-reativa

Queria uma explicação de forma clara e objetiva?

Li casos separados, mas queria saber os principais pontos que diferenciam os dois

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional/info e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55332/o-que-%C3%A9-reactive-programming-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-reativa, o que não entendeu mais exatamente?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3):

É complicado responder isso porque é como perguntar quais as diferenças entre laranjas e beterrabas. É, ambos são de comer, acabou.

[**Programação funcional**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101) é algo que tem como base o uso de funções para expressar código, que limitam a mudança de estado, ou seja é uma paradigma mesmo. E, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, não é só usar função, tem uma série de critérios. E funcional muito menos é o que usa função e procedural é o que usa procedimentos.

A [**programação reativa**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225324/101) é um estilo de organização do código, não é um paradigma (embora alguns classifique como se fosse), por isso podem ser usados juntos, é como usar a laranja para dar um sabor na beterraba. Programação reativa tem até mais a ver com arquitetura, com a forma como os dados são manipulados pela aplicação e como ela reage a eles. A linguagem ou código pode até ajudar fazer isso de forma mais simples.

De forma clara e objetiva é melhor aprender o que é cada um em isolado porque elas só se relacional por acaso, e não se antagonizam. Os *links* estão acima.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).