# Observable, quando usar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-6

Por que e quando devo utilizar o  Observable, quais suas vantagem e desvantagens e sua diferença se comparado com Promisses?

Comment: Essa pergunta está diretamente relacionada com a sua: [O que é Reactive Programming (Programação Reativa)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55332/o-que-%C3%A9-reactive-programming-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-reativa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trouxe esse artigo que foi publicado pelo **Wendel Nascimento** que encontrei para que você possa ver não só o que
> é mais também como usar, talvez você entenda melhor.
>
> Link de onde peguei a referencia para você verificar o Artigo Completo.:  https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular/

## O que é um Observable?

Por definição é uma coleção que funciona de forma unidirecional, ou seja, ele emite notificações sempre que ocorre uma mudança em um de seus itens e a partir disso podemos executar uma ação. Digamos que ele resolve o mesmo problema que a versão anterior do Angular havia resolvido com o $watch, porém sem usar força bruta. Enquanto no $watch verificamos todo nosso escopo por alterações após cada $digest cycle (o que tem um grande custo na performance), com Observable esta verificação não acontece, pois para cada evento é emitida uma notificação para nosso Observable e então tratamos os dados.

## O que faço com Observable? E onde entra Angular nessa história?

Vamos imaginar o consumo de uma web service, algo bem comum em aplicação Single Page, antes do Observable faríamos dessa maneira

```
getUsers(): Promise<User[]>{
  return fetch(myApiUrl)
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .catch(err=> Observable.throw(err.message));
```

}
O código acima é bem simples, estamos buscando um recurso (Uma lista de usuários) e após a resposta transformamos tudo em JSON.

Entretanto, o novo Angular foi construído pensando em aplicações reativas, abandonando o uso de Promises e adotando por padrão o Observable.

Usando Observable a mesma função ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
@Injectable()
class UserService {
 ...
 getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(myApiUrl)
                    .map(res=>res.json())
                    .catch(err=> Observable.throw(err.message));
 } 
 ...
}
```

Comment: Esse artigo já foi referenciado pela outra resposta, não vejo vantagens em copiar *ipsis litteris* parte dele como uma nova resposta.

Comment: Você verificou se é possível copiar o conteúdo de lá? Não tem uma notificação explícita, mas por padrão se não tem uma dizendo que pode copiar devemos entender que não pode.

Answer (score 2):

Tanto uma *Promise* quanto um *Observable* trazem abstrações para ajudar a lidar com eventos assíncronos.

Uma ***Promise*** lida com um único evento que pode ter sucesso ou falhar, enquanto um ***Observable*** lida com 0, 1 ou múltiplos eventos, disparando o callback especificado a cada um desses eventos.

A maior vantagem de um *Observable* é ter uma maior flexibilidade em relação a uma *Promise*, por exemplo, é possível cancelar uma requisição, retentar realizar uma ação, enquanto a *Promise* só possui dois estados que são de sucesso ou falha.

Um ótimo artigo relacionado a este tema é: https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular/