# Como funciona a programação reativa por trás?

Tags: programação-reativa

Eu estava lendo sobre programação reativa e me bateu uma dúvida: como funciona a programação reativa por debaixo dos panos? Que tipo de lógica existe por trás para ficar verificando qualquer alteração do usuário e mudar seu comportamento em real-time? É algum while infinito que fica verificando? (brincadeira)

Comment: Essa pergunta foi respondida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55332/o-que-%C3%A9-reactive-programming-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-reativa

Comment: Tem uma resposta interesse aqui:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55380/5748

Answer (score -1):

Pode-se dizer que a programação reativa é uma versão extendida e mais poderosa do padrão Observer. Dada a premissa de termos objetos observáveis como porta de entrada do programa, um dos pilares do modelo reativo é a idéia que “fluxos de dados” (que passaremos a chamar de streams) possam ser criados a partir de qualquer coisa: variáveis discretas, entradas de dados, propriedades da aplicação, ou como nos exemplos citados antes, eventos de UI ou entradas de aplicações externas…o importante a destacar aqui é que, independente de como a entrada do stream é construída, o código de manipulação dos eventos é o mesmo. Por exemplo, seu feed do Twitter, ou o listener de um tópico do Kafka, poderiam ser consumidos da mesma maneira que o click de um botão. O stream passa a ser apenas a abstração de uma origem de dados (potencialmente (e principalmente!) assíncronos), que emite valores de forma contínua, sobre os quais você pode reagir de acordo.

Comment: Então realmente é como se existisse um while na implementação que fica sempre verificando se a origem dos dados mudou??